# Parametrized Method in Java: try-catch does not catch ClassCastException (on Android)

Tags: java, android

Consider creating a new Object and casting it to String within a try-catch block that catches an Exception. Everything seems to be ok. But what does happen if we cast an Object to T within similar try-catch block in a parametrized function? The exception is not catched and the program crashes raising a ClassCastException.

Upd: thanks for answers and comments. But just to clarify: I understand why the exception is risen (because of casting Object to String obviously).

**The question is**: why does it NOT catch the ClassCastException during runtime in the method body?

```
class test
{
    public void doTests()
    {
        Log.i("", "====== CLASS CAST TEST ======");
        Log.i("", "====== REGULAR CAST TEST ");
        final String test1 = test.regularCastTest(); // the exception thrown is catched within the     method
        Log.i("", "====== PARAMETRIZED CAST TEST ");
        final String test2 = test.<String>parametrizedCastTest(); // fails here with     ClassCastException without catching it
        Log.i("", "------ CLASS CAST TEST END --");
    }   
    static <T> T parametrizedCastTest()
    {
        Object obj = new Object();
        try
        {
            final T ret = (T) obj;
            Log.d("", String.format("%s; %s",     obj.getClass().getSimpleName(), ret.getClass().getSimpleName())); // does not fail and prints 'Object; Object'
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    static String regularCastTest()
    {
        Object obj = new Object();
        try
        {
            final String ret = (String) obj;
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

PS: the parametrized method does not fail if we simply call it without getting the result like:

```
test.<String>parametrizedCastTest();
```

**LOGCAT**

```
11-26 19:13:37.692: I/(13018): ====== CLASS CAST TEST ======
11-26 19:13:37.692: I/(13018): ====== REGULAR CAST TEST 
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.test.regularCastTest(test.java:57)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.test.go1(test.java:30)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.AppGoods.doTests(AppGoods.java:285)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.AppGoods.onCreate(AppGoods.java:188)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/System.err(13018):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 19:13:37.692: I/(13018): ====== PARAMETRIZED CAST TEST 
11-26 19:13:37.692: D/(13018): Object; Object
11-26 19:13:37.692: D/AndroidRuntime(13018): Shutting down VM
11-26 19:13:37.692: W/dalvikvm(13018): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a2ce0)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018): Process: com.kaypu.goods, PID: 13018
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.kaypu.goods.AppGoods: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4476)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.test.go1(test.java:32)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.AppGoods.doTests(AppGoods.java:285)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at com.kaypu.goods.AppGoods.onCreate(AppGoods.java:188)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
11-26 19:13:37.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13018):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Absolutely. Just tested it again. It prints object types in the parametrized method and then crashes at assigning the _italic_ test2 constant.

Comment: I believe this is because of type erasure.  The program simply is not capable of checking whether `obj` can be cast to `T`, because at runtime it doesn't actually know anything about what `T` is.

Comment: @323go That isn't legal.  You can't use `instanceof` on a generic type  parameter.

Comment: Oh, type erasure. Fun stuff. nvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way type erasure is implemented,

```
final T ret = (T) obj;
```

is actually translated to

```
final Object ret = (Object) obj;
```

and the actual implementation of `parametrizedCastTest` returns an `Object`, but anywhere it's *called*, the cast is done there:

```
final String test2 = Test.<String> parametrizedCastTest();
```

becomes

```
final String test2 = (String) Test.parametrizedCastTest();
```

which is why the CCE happens in a different place than you expected.

As a general rule, generic methods are implemented by replacing type variables by their upper bound (Object, in this case), and then their *call sites* secretly do the actual casting to the type you're supposed to get out.

Comment: I didn't expect translating T into Object though I should've. That makes sense now. Thanks! Marked as an accepted answer.

Comment: One more reason to hate java... for real, that behavior is a pure non-sense, completely unexpected for developers and inconsistent in regards to other languages. They should have stick to the C++ way that works fine and makes more sense. It even makes things harder: how do you want to do a generic "safeGet" function if it hides the type you are referring to? That reduces the entire use of genericity to a pathetic level, really disappointed by such a behavior :/ Thanks forthe answer anyway, you saved me bunch of time!

Answer (score 1):

You should have gotten a warning here

```
final T ret = (T) obj;
```

about an unsafe cast.

Within a generic method, all you know about a declared type parameter is its bound(s). You've declared the type parameter as

```
static <T> T parametrizedCastTest() {
```

with no bounds. In other words, it reduces to `Object`.  The cast here

```
final T ret = (T) obj;
```

is unsafe because `T`, which is used as a return type, can actually be anything else. And in your example it is.

```
final String test2 = Test.<String> parametrizedCastTest(); // fails here with ClassCastException without catching it
```

You're trying to assign an object of type `Object` to a variable of type `String`. This will never work.